# Distant SQL connexion with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm writing a code for creating a database and a user for phpmyadmin on a distant sql server in CodeIgniter.

So, how can I open a single SQL connexion in a function of CodeIgniter without using the built in class ($this->db) for executing distant creation queries ?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to use the built-in facility, what's the problem then? Just do it as you'd do if you weren't using the framework. I suspect there's something you haven't mentioned. Probably, you *want* to use the built-in class but are unsure about how to have *two* simultaneous connections—am I right?

Comment: Hmm yes, I want to stay in the "framework-think way" so having two simultaneous connections is a good thing but if it isn't possible, I'll make with classic sql driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any SQL query by:

```
$this->db->query("your query code");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make two database connections (do you?), you should [check the user guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide//database/connecting.html). You can do this:

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('group_one', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('group_two', TRUE);
```

Where `group_one` and `group_two` are the keys in your database config array (check user guide for full example).

Then you can do this:

```
$DB1->query();
$DB1->result();
```